# Listen to changes of a file in cloud

Tags: android

once i gained persistant access to a file in a cloud picked by the user using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setType("application/json");
startActivityForResult(intent, IMPORT);
```

and

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

is there a way to listen to changes made to that file outside the app? Or would i have to check it myself with some time interval? If so, can i get the last modified date without downloading the whole file?

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)` Please remove that flag. It does nothing. And innocent readers might think its needed. Dont confuse.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to listen to changes made to that file outside the app?

No, sorry.

> Or would i have to check it myself with some time interval?

Presumably yes.

> If so, can i get the last modified date without downloading the whole file?

Wrap the document `Uri` in `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()`, then [call `lastModified()` on the `DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile?hl=en#lastModified()). Note that the value of this is up to the cloud document provider and may or may not be up to date.